# Unsuccessful start when pushing a Python Flask web service in IBM Cloud using CLI

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to upload a web service developed in python using the Flask library to IBM Cloud using the IBM CLI.
When the web service starts in the cloud, it waits for its start "Waiting for app to start ..." until the message "Start unsuccessful" and a FAILED error.
Below I put everything obtained from the logs when working with this application

app.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

# On Bluemix, get the port number from the environment variable PORT
# When running this app on the local machine, default the port to 8000
port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8000))
```

```
###################### /API ENDPOINTS ##############################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Procfile

```
web: python app.py
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.12.1
pymongo==3.7.2
```

I've alredy try with requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.0.2
pymongo==3.7.2
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath( path.dirname( __file__ ) )

# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='app-name',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='First flask web service',
    long_description=long_description,
    url='',
    license='Apache-2.0'
)
```

Here is error in the log file:

```
2019-05-16T17:14:06.98-0600 [STG/0] OUT        Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, click, itsdangerous, Flask, pymongo
2019-05-16T17:14:07.93-0600 [STG/0] OUT        Successfully installed Flask-0.12.1 Jinja2-2.10.1 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Werkzeug-0.15.4 click-7.0 itsdangerous-1.1.0 pymongo-3.7.2
2019-05-16T17:14:08.14-0600 [STG/0] ERR        You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.1.1 is available.
2019-05-16T17:14:08.14-0600 [STG/0] ERR        You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
2019-05-16T17:14:23.14-0600 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 0
2019-05-16T17:14:23.14-0600 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
2019-05-16T17:14:23.14-0600 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet...
2019-05-16T17:14:23.14-0600 [STG/0] OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
2019-05-16T17:14:23.89-0600 [API/11] OUT Creating droplet for app with guid eeca8680-0347-4fc4-9c18-2b7576616234
2019-05-16T17:14:24.07-0600 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (33.1M)
2019-05-16T17:14:28.05-0600 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded droplet (34.9M)
2019-05-16T17:14:28.06-0600 [STG/0] OUT Uploading complete
2019-05-16T17:14:28.85-0600 [STG/0] OUT Cell a4f5548f-f92e-4c73-9bff-ec12545dd5b3 stopping instance 42d8c7ac-a894-4dc8-8280-8a6432c9c4f1
2019-05-16T17:14:28.85-0600 [STG/0] OUT Cell a4f5548f-f92e-4c73-9bff-ec12545dd5b3 destroying container for instance 42d8c7ac-a894-4dc8-8280-8a6432c9c4f1
2019-05-16T17:14:30.33-0600 [CELL/0] OUT Cell ff070f2e-7593-45a0-8685-9c270aedfe81 creating container for instance da48fb2e-4bf0-4d55-4f60-e021
2019-05-16T17:14:30.66-0600 [STG/0] OUT Cell a4f5548f-f92e-4c73-9bff-ec12545dd5b3 successfully destroyed container for instance 42d8c7ac-a894-4dc8-8280-8a6432c9c4f1
2019-05-16T17:14:33.65-0600 [CELL/0] OUT Cell ff070f2e-7593-45a0-8685-9c270aedfe81 successfully created container for instance da48fb2e-4bf0-4d55-4f60-e021
2019-05-16T17:14:38.26-0600 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
2019-05-16T17:14:41.14-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-05-16T17:14:41.14-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR  * Restarting with stat
2019-05-16T17:14:41.15-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-16T17:14:41.15-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "app.py", line 227, in <module>
2019-05-16T17:14:41.15-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True, threaded=True)
2019-05-16T17:14:41.15-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1007, in run_simple
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     errread, errwrite)
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     raise child_exception
2019-05-16T17:14:41.16-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2019-05-16T17:14:41.33-0600 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
2019-05-16T17:14:41.35-0600 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0
2019-05-16T17:14:47.56-0600 [API/8] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
2019-05-16T17:14:47.59-0600 [API/8] OUT App instance exited with guid eeca8680-0347-4fc4-9c18-2b7576616234 payload: {"instance"=>"da48fb2e-4bf0-4d55-4f60-e021", "index"=>0, "cell_id"=>"f
f070f2e-7593-45a0-8685-9c270aedfe81", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1558048487492260855, "version"=>"c4
982556-7c37-40bf-972b-03f8b9cde9da"}
```

Comment: What is in line 227 of app.py? The error log refers to that line. Add the manifest.yml and the push command to the question.

Comment: Can u edit Procfile and change it to `web: python .\app.py`

Comment: Usually `web: python theappname.py` works. No need to change

Comment: The line 227 is the last part of the program, you can find in the API ENDPOINT section above:
`###################### /API ENDPOINTS ##############################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True, threaded=True)`

And the manifest.yml is the next:
`---
applications:
 - name: liza-speakfreely-suite
   memory: 256M`

@data_henrik

Comment: The push command is "ibmcloud app push"  @data_henrik

Comment: Is the README.md present that you try to opne? Have you experimented simplifying your setup.py?

Comment: well actually I tried using some simple setup.py, the result is the next:

`from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='app-name',
    install_requires=[
        "flask"
    ]
)`

The problem is the same, got stock when try to start @data_henrik